# Middleman: run custom action after build

Tags: ruby, middleman

How can I run custom action (eg. copy file to build folder) after middleman built pages?

I want to put `Readme.md` file from source to build dir.

Comment: I'm not familiar with middleman, but it looks like it runs in the terminal, so you could make a bash script to call middleman and then move the files into the correct folder.

Comment: I guess you also mean outside source - because all files within the source folder will be copied into the build by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `after_build` hook. add following code to `config.rb`.

The hook which you can use is written in https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/ .

Although it is not well documented, it seems that `after_build` can use directly in `config.rb`, without writing your own extension.

```
after_build do |builder|
  src = File.join(config[:source],"Readme.md")
  dst = File.join(config[:build_dir],"Readme.md")
  builder.thor.source_paths << File.dirname(__FILE__)
  builder.thor.copy_file(src,dst)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the `after_build` hook is a default answer, i would suggest using a task runner to do the job.

A task runner is awesome to make such routines easier. For example, most Middleman projects require deployment to a hosting server. So if you happen to use a task runner for deployment, you could use it for copying the file as well.

If you don't use a task runner, consider using one. It will save you a lot of nuisance.

[Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is the natural choice for Middleman's Ruby environment, but i prefer [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Here's a Grunt copy task (uses the [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) plugin):

```
copy: {
  bowercomponents: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: [
          'source/Readme.md'
        ],
        dest: 'build/',
        filter: 'isFile'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here's a deployment task using the [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) plugin:

```
shell: {

    buildAndPublish: {
        command: [
          'echo "### Building ###"',
          'bundle exec middleman build --verbose',

          'echo "### Adding built files to git index ###"',
          'cd build/',
          'git add -A',

          'echo "### Commiting changes ###"',
          'git commit -m build',

          'echo "### Pushing the commit to the gh-pages remote branch ###"',
          'git push origin gh-pages',
          'cd ..'
        ].join(' && '),
        options: {
          stdout: true,
          stderr: true
        }
    }

}
```